# clang-format: How to keep line feeds after access modifiers?

Tags: c++, clang-format

What I'm getting:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  int stuff;

  int otherStuff;
}
```

What I'd like to get (or preserve) is:

```
class Foo
{
public:

  int stuff;

  int otherStuff;
}
```

How can I prevent `clang-format` from removing my line feeds after access modifier indentation?

Comment: What are your MaxEmptyLinesToKeep and KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks? I don't know if latter applies, but may be worth testing out.

Comment: Don't seem to have any effect. Maybe that's not supported at all..